# Update duplicate values of the column of a table in oracle

Tags: oracle19c

I have a table in which there are duplicate records.

[image: Before]

I want this to be like below

[image: After]

Please help me on this.

Comment: What is your logic, what have you tried so far, and what issues are you having? It looks like maybe a gaps-and-islands correction, but isn't entirely clear how you get from the first image to the second (and please post formatted text, not images) - whether the row that initially has 22-Oct is updated or not, for instance, and what order the rows are set; which might not matter is that is the complete table, but might if there are other columns you haven't shown. Are the times all set to midnight, or are these actually real splits part way through each day - so not really duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I think that you might use a "window SQL" function. This allows you to group rows, for instance to show duplicates in the right order (and potentially eliminate or update them. For instance take a look at the following example where I show the duplicates of the first two dates in your data set ordered by the different values for the third date. I then de-duplicate the data set, keeping only the first value for date3 for each pair of date1, date2.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@tiger
Connected.
SQL> set echo on
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-RR';

Session altered.

SQL> drop table test;

Table TEST dropped.

SQL> create table test (
  2     col1    number,
  3     d1      date,
  4     d2      date,
  5     d3      date);

Table TEST created.

SQL> insert into test values (1,'01-mar-21','03-sep-21','21-oct-21');

1 row inserted.

SQL> insert into test values (1,'01-mar-21','21-oct-21','21-oct-21');

1 row inserted.

SQL> insert into test values (1,'01-mar-21','21-oct-21','21-oct-21');

1 row inserted.

SQL> insert into test values (1,'01-mar-21','21-oct-21','22-oct-21');

1 row inserted.

SQL> insert into test values (1,'01-mar-21','22-oct-21','22-oct-21');

1 row inserted.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> -- show duplicates on d1, d2 order by d3
SQL> select row_number()
  2  over (partition by d1, d2 order by d3) rn, t.d1, t.d2, t.d3
  3  from test t;

   RN           D1           D2           D3
_____ ____________ ____________ ____________
    1 01-MAR-21    03-SEP-21    21-OCT-21
    1 01-MAR-21    21-OCT-21    21-OCT-21
    2 01-MAR-21    21-OCT-21    21-OCT-21
    3 01-MAR-21    21-OCT-21    22-OCT-21
    1 01-MAR-21    22-OCT-21    22-OCT-21
```

Notice that rn is incremented for each d3 within a given pair of d1,d2

```
SQL> -- eliminate the duplicates on d1, d2 (keep first one)
SQL> select x.* from (select row_number() over (partition by d1, d2 order by d3) rn, t.d1, t.d2, t.d3
  2  from test t )x where x.rn=1;

   RN           D1           D2           D3
_____ ____________ ____________ ____________
    1 01-MAR-21    03-SEP-21    21-OCT-21
    1 01-MAR-21    21-OCT-21    21-OCT-21
    1 01-MAR-21    22-OCT-21    22-OCT-21
```